# whatsapp web with react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview

Trying to make an react native android app which loads whatsapp web, but upon loading it loads the mobile page rather than loading desktop page?

I have also added the useragent still whatsapp seems to detect the mobile window and show mobile webpage.

Any solution how can I force whatsapp to open desktop site on my react native app?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://web.whatsapp.com/" }}
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `contentMode="desktop"` as a prop to your WebView component, but it looks like this is only supported on iOS 13+ as of now (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#contentmode)

In context of your WebView component:

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: "https://web.whatsapp.com/" }}
    userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0"
    contentMode="desktop"
/>
```

Comment: So there is no solution to this in android?

Comment: From what I can find, there is no solution to this in android using that specific WebView component. There could be alternative react-native libraries that have that support, or you could write android native code alongside your react-native code.

Comment: Any alternative library you know which could help me on this ?

Comment: So I was looking to see if I could find one for you that meets your requirements. So far no luck unfortunately, but if I find a working solution I will update my answer.

Comment: any update to the above?